# How can I connect to Exchange server remotely through Powershell and a PSSessionConfiguration

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, powershell-remoting

I am trying to connect to exchange remotely and run queries from Powershell.

This is my configuration file on the Exchange server:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "Exchange" -StartupScript "C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\RemoteExchange.ps1"
```

This is how I am connecting from my local computer:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName cmsexch -ConfigurationName "Exchange" -Authentication Kerberos -credential $cred
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

> New-PSSession : Running startup script threw an error: Cannot find path 'HKLM:\Software\microsoft\ExchangeServer\v14\CentralAdmin' because it does 
>   not exist..

**NOTE:**

- My local Powershell is running on Windows 2008 SP2 **32 bits**
- My remote Exchange is running on Windows 2008 R2 SP1 **64 bits**

**QUESTIONS:**

- How can I fix this issue?
- Is this because the registry redirector on
  Windows 64 bits?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The connection string from your local computer appears to be missing a few things. I believe that the following code is what you're looking for. You would need to fill in your FQDN and that's about it. These 3 lines get me right in. The 32/64 bit should make no difference.

```html
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<FQDN of your Exchange server>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential

Import-PSSession $Session
```

This TechNet Exchange Knowledge Article might elaborate or at least point you in the right direction.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx